# AdalException AADSTS90122: User identifier is not present

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I get the following exception:
**AADSTS90122: User identifier is not present**

while calling:
**authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCred, userAssertion)**

full code:

```
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
string userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;

string userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);
string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, null); 

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCred, userAssertion);
```

100% verified parameters and right to have access.
The code was working for MONTHS, just yesterday started to hang :/

Comment: Exactly the issue I am facing. Stopped working from 7/4/17 in local machines and now fails in deployed azure websites too! Yet to find a solution to it

Comment: Not sure if this is some azureAD issue... Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: There is an ongoing investigation into this error, will follow up.

Comment: @dstrockis any link to the investigation on what really happened and how it got resolved ?

Comment: It was a regression with Azure AD that was fixed on 4/13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue with Azure Active directory seems to be fixed now. I'm able to acquire token on behalf of user successfully using UserAssertion and ClientCredentials now (from 13 Apr). This was not working for the past couple of days for sure.